# Which technologies to create web interface for scientific instrument?

Tags: c#, web-applications

I am working on software for some scientific instrumentation. An embedded computer running Windows 7 is inside the instrument, which controls various components of the device; cameras, motors, thermometers, etc. I've written a basic interface in WPF/C# and use remote desktop to test the application. (Reason is safety, the instrument will be used in high radiation areas).

What I want:
A server runs on the embedded PC. The user accesses a web page at 192.168.x.x (Internet access would be nice, but not necessary) and clicks 'collect data' and the server loads the relevant C# .dll's, acquires data and uploads the data to the user. Speed/scalability is not much of a concern, as data acquisition could take anywhere from minutes to days.

What I'm confused about:
How do I go about executing my existing C# code from a web application? i.e., which .NET technology(ies) should I look into using?

Comment: If you are connecting to it via a browser, yes, its a web application.  There's probably a good question here, but you should pick a single, *answerable* question to focus on.

Comment: Much more answerable :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I go about executing my existing C# code from a web
>   application? i.e., which .NET technology(ies) should I look into
>   using?

If your goal is for your web application (i.e., the application running on the embedded machine) to run your C# code, you would probably want to have an ASP.Net application running on the embedded machine.  Assuming you don't want to run IIS on your embedded machine (because it uses too excessive resources), I suggest using [Cassini](https://code.google.com/p/cassini/).

If the C# code is client-side, just give the web application some web services (e.g., using REST or SOAP) and call them from your C# application.